# sort a list of numbers from highest to lowest

Tags: c++, sorting

I am struggling with sorting a list of numbers using custom function for sort. I know how to sort vector, but i can't sort a list.

I want to sort list from highest to lowest number.
Here is code that I am using

```
list.sort(my_sort);
```

And here is a function my_sort

```
bool my_sort ( int a, int b)
{
return a.size() > b.size;
}
```

Comment: `return a.size() > b.size;` ?? Maybe `return a > b;`

Comment: `int`s don't have a `size`. Why are you trying to call a `size` method?

Comment: Maybe you just wanted: `list.sort(std::greater<int>());` and not use your own comparison anyways.

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/), it show a good example of what you want to do.

Comment: All `int`s have the same size, see `sizeof(int)`.  Other integers, `short` and `long` have different sizes.  The *size* of an integer refers to how much memory it occupies.

Comment: Off topic: A function with a name like `my_sort` should sort, not compare. Recommend changing the name to `my_compare` to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use

list.sort()

and

list.sort(std::greater());

to get the ascending and descending order.

You can check the following link:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort

Answer (score 0):

As user2357112 hinted, you should have:

```
bool my_sort ( int a, int b)
{
    return a > b;
}
```